# Variable before CodeMirror function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, codemirror

I want to get Value from CodeMirror textarea whose name I have in Cookie. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
  var formname = $.cookie("formname");
  var formcode = formname.getValue();
```

Firebug says: formname.getValue is not a function

Thank you very much. I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`formname` is a string. A string does not have such a method called `getValue`. Seeing the appearance of `$.cookie("formname")`, I assume that you're using JQUery.

Code:

```
var formname = $.cookie("formname");
var formcode = $('textarea[name="'+formname+'"]').val(); //JQuery method:
// Selects an input element whose name equals `formname` and gets the value of it.

//var formcode = document.getElementById(formname).value;
// Another method: Without use of JQuery, assuming that the textarea's id equals formname
```

Comment: FireBug: unterminated string literal ... ?

Comment: My bad, fixed now. Do you know how to recognise and debug JavaScript errors? `unterminated string literal` means that a string has been started using a quotation mark, but no ending mark can be found.

Comment: I know. I wanted to edit your post but i don´t have privileages to do it. But no, your solution don´t help me. getValue is from CodeMirror API(http://codemirror.net/manual.html#api).

Comment: Updated answer. It will get the content of a textarea with the `name` attribute set to `formname`. I have commented another option, which selects the textarea whose id equals `formname`.

Comment: Yes i tried it... But i must save(http://codemirror.net/manual.html#save) CodeMirror textarea before i can get value from it. Becouse there are no charecters in textarea before i save() the CodeMirror. I ask how to save CodeMirrors in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463644/save-all-codemirrors-on-page