# Save all CodeMirrors on page

Tags: javascript, codemirror

How I can [save()](http://codemirror.net/manual.html#save) all CodeMirror textareas on one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to cache all CodeMirror instances in to an array, and then loop through that array `save()`'ing each instance.

```
var CMInstances = [instance1, instance2, ..., instanceN];
for (instance in CMInstances) {
  instance.save();
}
```

I'd assume at some point in your script you're setting up your CodeMirror instances, so that point would be ideal to cache them.